# Showing if $x_n\rightharpoonup x_0$ in normed space $X$ implies $x_0\in\overline{\text{span}}\{x_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I am trying to solve the following problem:

If $x_n\rightharpoonup x_0$ in a normed space $X$, show that $x_0\in \overline{Y}$, where $Y=\text{span}\{x_n\}$.

$\textbf{My attempt is as follows:}$

From the weak convergence $x_n\rightharpoonup x_0$ we have that for all $f\in X'$ that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0)$. Assume that $x_0\not\in\overline{Y}$, i.e., $x\in X\setminus\overline{Y}$. I now apply the following lemma (the problem advised me to use this) that says there exists a functional $\tilde{f}\in X’$ such that $\tilde{f}(x)=0$ for all $x\in\overline{Y}$ and $\tilde{f}(x_0)=\delta$ where $\delta=\underset{x\in\overline{Y}}{\inf}||x-x_0||$. Since $x_0\not\in\overline{Y}$ this implies that $\delta > 0$. We have that $x_n\in Y\subset\overline{Y}$ thus $x_n\in\overline{Y}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This shows that $\tilde{f}(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But this leads to $\tilde{f}(x_n)\not\rightarrow\tilde{f}(x_0)$ since $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\tilde{f}(x_n)=0\neq\delta > 0$. This is a contradiction to the weak convergence $x_n\rightharpoonup x_0$ since $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0)$ should hold for all $f\in X'$. Therefore, the assumption that $x_0\not\in\overline{Y}$ must be wrong hence $x_0\in\overline{Y}$.

$\textbf{Comments}:$ I believe this is correct, but I would still appreciate some feedback! Furthermore, I'm also a bit worried if there's something in this proof that I should elaborate on more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is correct. In general for a convex set $S$, $\overline{S}^\text{weak}=\overline{S}^{||\cdot||}$.

Comment: Thanks for verifying it! What exactly do you mean by $\overline{S}^{\text{weak}}=\overline{S}^{||\cdot||}$? And how do you know whether $Y$ is a convex set?

Comment: $\overline{S}^\text{weak}$ refers to the closure of $S$ with respect to the weak topology on $V$ and $\overline{S}^{||\cdot||}$ refers to the closure of $S$ with respect to the norm topology of $V$. Convexity of a linear subspace $Y$ of $V$ is essentially by definition (for any two points $x,y\in Y$, the line segment $tx+(1-t)y,\,0\le t\le 1$ is also in $Y$)

Comment: The result holds due to a more general form of Hahn Banach (Hahn Banach Theorem for Convex Sets)